# Fetching one-level children from a tree

Tags: javascript

I have the following tree structure:

```
var struct = {
    name: 'folder1',
    type: 'folder',
    children: [
        {
            name: 'child1',
            type: 'child',
            children: []
        },
        {
            name: 'child2',
            type: 'child',
            children: []
        },
        {
            name: 'folder2',
            type: 'folder',
            children: []
        },
        {
            name: 'folder3',
            type: 'folder',
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'child3',
                    type: 'child',
                    children: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

And I want to get a map of folders to children, but without any nested children.

So for the above structure, for folder1, I should get only `child1`, `child2`, `folder2`, and `folder3`, without the nested inside the last `child3`.

How should I do this?

Right now I have the following code:

```
var getMap = function (data, map) {
        var elements = document.createDocumentFragment();
        for (var i in data) {
            var nameId = data[i].name.split(' ').join('');
            if (data[i].type == "child") {
                var element = something;
            } else {
                var element = somethingElse;
            }
            elements.appendChild(element);
            if (data[i].type === "folder") {
                var element = createMainElement(getMap(data[i].children, map));
                map[data[i].id] = element.innerHTML;
                elements.appendChild(element);
            }
        }
        return elements;
    };
```

And it works, but it gets me all nested elements.

EDIT.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/1nbvjzre/
```

Here's the fiddle - folder1 shouldn't contain child3 in console log.

Comment: I think you have a syntax error in your JS (probably a copy paste error) at the `}  } else {`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I corrected it and added a fiddle to be more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Loop the children property of your "struct" var, you shoud get only the first level of childrens

```
struct.children.forEach(function(child){
   console.log(child.name)
});
```

Hope this helps.